# Colorscheme change when filetype changes

Tags: vim, detection, file-type

Is it possible to change the colorscheme in Vim  when I open a .vim, .htm, .html, .xml or the _vimrc file?
(also change colorscheme when I switch to an already open file with above extension)

This is what I want my vim to do:

file = txt or a new (not saved) buffer: colorscheme1 (default colorscheme)
file = vimrc, vim, html, htm: colorscheme2

I noted also that my vim doesn't detect all filetypes.
Text files are not recognized as text file.

ps:
If this is not possible would it be possible to switch to another colorscheme and keep it when I restart VIM (without changing something in vimrc)?

---

**edit**:

Found the solution with an autocmd:

```
augroup filetype_colorscheme
    au BufEnter *
    \ if !exists('b:colors_name')
        \ | if &ft == "vim" || &ft == "html"
            \ | let b:colors_name = 'colorscheme 2'
        \ | else
            \ | let b:colors_name = 'colorscheme 1'
        \ | endif
    \ | endif
    \ | exe 'colorscheme' b:colors_name
augroup END
```

***still one problem**:

  above code changes the colorscheme of all files in a split window when I click in a buffer*
  Is there a way to desactivate (and reactivate) an autocmd using a shortcut key?

Comment: How does vim recognizes text files?

Comment: @black, it doesn't in my case

Comment: Yes, got it... I wanted to ask what type does vim 'use' instead of text.

Comment: @black, oh sorry, text files aren't recognized at all.

Comment: This one did the trick: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt set filetype=txt`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to achieve something close to what you want with the following autocommands:

```
colo <colourscheme1>  "default
autocmd! BufEnter,BufNewFile *.html,*.vim,*xml colo <colourscheme2>
autocmd! BufLeave *.html,*.vim,*xml colo <colourscheme1>
```

And of course you can modify the list of file extensions as you wish. The colourscheme will be `<colourscheme1>` by default, or `<colourscheme2>` if you open (or switch to) any of the specified types, and will revert to `<colourscheme1>` when you open (or switch to) any other type within a Vim session.

Hope this helps.