# How to change vim color for a particular tab?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have many files opened in tab. Some of the files are from a different project and are there for reference. I want these files to be in some other colorscheme so that i can distinguish them easily.

Is it possible to do such a thing.

If yes can someone point me as to how to do that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean the color of a tab or the colorscheme of the code?

Comment: you can suggest either one. I would prefer the colorscheme of the code. else the color of the tab would also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the *color scheme* is global, but you can use `:autocmd` to change it dynamically (but only one is ever visible at the same time, see [how to get different colorschemes in vim split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062491/how-to-get-different-colorschemes-in-vim-split-window?rq=1).

Have a look at the [tabpagecolorscheme plugin](https://github.com/ujihisa/tabpagecolorscheme); this gets you a distinct colorscheme **per tab page**.